# Select multiple con datos de ambas tablas MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

Estoy tratando de realizar un query en el que seleccione varios datos de ambas tablas donde su relación sea el NickName

al principio para tomar los mensajes tenia este codigo

```
SELECT * FROM $tabla WHERE UserEmitter IN ('$usuarioActual', 
'$usuarioReceptor') AND UserReceiver IN ('$usuarioReceptor', '$usuarioActual') 
AND seen = 1 ORDER BY created_at ASC
```

pero ahora quiero tomar tambien la imagen de cada usuario para mostrarlas en la vista, intento realizarlo con

```
SELECT DISTINCT m.*
FROM messages m
WHERE m.UserEmitter IN ('cesgdav', 'cesgdav2') AND m.UserReceiver IN ('cesgdav2', 'cesgdav') AND seen = 1
ORDER BY created_at ASC
(SELECT picture
FROM users u
WHEREu.nickname IN ('cesgdav', 'cesgdav2'))
```

pero al correr el query me indica un error en el segundo select

Comment: si la segunda subconsulta hace parte del ORDER BY te falta la "," coma, aunque no le veo cual es la funcion de ella

Comment: `SELECT DISTINCT m.*,(SELECT picture
FROM users u
WHEREu.nickname IN ('cesgdav', 'cesgdav2'))
FROM messages m
WHERE m.UserEmitter IN ('cesgdav', 'cesgdav2') AND m.UserReceiver IN ('cesgdav2', 'cesgdav') AND seen = 1
ORDER BY created_at ASC` Intenta asi

Comment: @YoAlbert me dice que el subquery retorna mas de 1 fila

Comment: `SELECT DISTINCT m.*,(SELECT picture FROM users u WHEREu.nickname IN ('cesgdav', 'cesgdav2' LIMIT 1)) FROM messages m WHERE m.UserEmitter IN ('cesgdav', 'cesgdav2') AND m.UserReceiver IN ('cesgdav2', 'cesgdav') AND seen = 1 ORDER BY created_at ASC` ahi debe funcionar de una manera, pero lo que realmente debes hacer es un inner join, voy a redactar la respuesta

Answer (score 0):

En mi humilde conocimiento, debes de realizar un `inner join`;

```
SELECT DISTINCT m.*,users.campo_nuevo
FROM messages m
INNER JOIN users ON users.campo_comun = messages.campo_comun
WHERE m.UserEmitter IN ('cesgdav', 'cesgdav2') AND m.UserReceiver IN ('cesgdav2', 'cesgdav') AND seen = 1
ORDER BY created_at ASC
```

Te explico, aca lo que se esta haciendo es unir las 2 tablas por 1 campo en comun, en tu caso seria `"nickname"` (?), en la sección del `SELECT` agregas el campo que quieres de la tabla que estas uniendo.

En caso que desees ampliar un poco mas esta informacion sobre https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_inner.asp